# How to verify that my uImage is good?

Tags: kernel, u-boot

I had a zImage file and I used mkimage tool to convert it into a uImage format. 
When I am booting this file, it is not been found by u-boot:

```
Wrong Image Format for bootm command
ERROR: can't get kernel image!
U-Boot-PetaLinux>
```

So I thought of verifying that the uImage generated after conversion with mkimage  is a valid image or not.

The exact command that I used is:

```
mkimage -A arm -O linux -T kernel -C none -a 0x80008000 -e 0x80008000 -n "Linux kernel" -d zImage uImage
```

How do I verify this image?

Comment: Is [this](http://www.trimslice.com/wiki/index.php/U-Boot_images) of any assistance? I'm using ptxdist and barebox, so I can't help you much more I think...

Comment: Try with uncompressed image (`vmlinux`) instead of `zImage`. Or simply do `make uimage` and let the kernel makefile do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command `file` in Linux to check the file type.

`file` recognizes many different types of files by their header and can tell a lot of details besides (load address, entry points of uImage, all will be displayed to you). And from this info you can decide for yourself if your file is correctly generated (esp. the loading address, usually, is the problem).